# HTC one x doesn't remember debug mode

Tags: android, eclipse, android-debug, htc-android

When I connect any Android Smartphone which I previously used to debug to my pc, normally it automatically sets the debug mode enabled. Somehow since a few weeks my HTC one X stopped doing this. Everytime I connect my smartphone I have to manually select the USB Debug mode to be on.

[image]

**UPDATE**

It looks like the bug could be even worse. If I switch my top right button to on, but leave the bottom "debug mode" off, my phone still starts debug mode. After a while it somehow detected that it wasn't in debug mode and jumped back out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple, simply disable and enable the Debug options (top right button "ON")

**UPDATE**
Though it worked for a day or so, the trick didn't last long

**UPDATE**
Software update did the trick. Apparently this bug was only present in 4.2.2 (at least in combination with HTC sense)

Comment: Check if there is some kind of energy saving mode that might be overriding that setting, or some kind of new security setting that could be overriding that setting as well (after all, debug mode leaves a big security hole in the event someone gets physical access to the device). If that leads nowhere, I'd install adb wifi and I'd root the phone (in case that particular phone requires the phone to be rooted to be able to use adb wifi).

Comment: I suppose you could also try factory resetting the phone to see if any third party application you recently installed would be interfering with adb. For instance, there are some usb tethering apps that are known to interfere with adb, because some of them use adb under the hood.

Comment: I did try the factory reset and found it wasn't just done by a third part application. I also tried reïnstalling HTC manager which also didn't help. I will have a look at the energy saving mode though